# Unexpected row getting changed in pandas loc assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to copy a portion of a pandas dataframe onto a different portion, overwriting the existing values there.  I am using `.loc` but more rows are changing than the ones I am referencing.

My example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    'col2': range(1, 6),
    'col3': range(6, 11)
})

print(df)

  col1  col2  col3
0    A     1     6
1    B     2     7
2    C     3     8
3    D     4     9
4    E     5    10
```

I want to write the values of `col2` and `col3` from the `C` and `D` rows onto the `A` and `B` rows. Using `.loc`:

```
df.loc[0:2, ["col2", "col3"]] = df.loc[2:4, ["col2", "col3"]].values

print(df)

  col1  col2  col3
0    A     3     8
1    B     4     9
2    C     5    10
3    D     4     9
4    E     5    10
```

This does what I want for rows `A` and `B`, but row `C` has also changed.  I expect only the first two rows to change, i.e. my expected output is

```
  col1  col2  col3
0    A     3     8
1    B     4     9
2    C     3     8
3    D     4     9
4    E     5    10
```

Why did the `C` row also change, and how may I do this with only changing the first two rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike list slicing [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) slicing is inclusive-inclusive

> **Warning** Note that contrary to usual python slices, **both** the start and the stop
> are included

so you should do

```
df.loc[0:1, ["col2", "col3"]] = df.loc[2:3, ["col2", "col3"]].values
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition, you can also pass a **list** of exhaustive elements, this way the rows need not to be consecutive:

```
df.loc[[0,1], ["col2", "col3"]] = df.loc[[2,3], ["col2", "col3"]].values
```

Answer (score 1):

You went too far with the indices:

```py
df.loc[0:1, ["col2", "col3"]] = df.loc[2:3, ["col2", "col3"]].values
```